# Can you use curses syntax with normal python functions?

Tags: python

I want to create a software program that has a main menu with options that are navigable with arrow keys (I have the code for this). When the user clicks on the option they want, it loads in the associated function. Can I use normal python syntax as the function and have the curses syntax call the function? How can I do this?

```
import curses

menu = ['Set Wallet Address', 'Start BTC Miner', 'Currency', 'Exit']

def clr():
    print("\n"*60)

#center everything
def print_menu(stdscr, selected_row_idx):
    stdscr.clear()
    h, w = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    for idx, row in enumerate(menu):
        x = w//2 - len(row)//2
        y = h//2 - len(menu)//2 + idx
        if idx == selected_row_idx:
            stdscr.attron(curses.color_pair(1))
            stdscr.addstr(y, x, row)
            stdscr.attroff(curses.color_pair(1))
        else:
            stdscr.addstr(y, x, row)    
            stdscr.refresh()

#print everything in center
def print_center(stdscr, text):
    stdscr.clear()
    h, w = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    x = w//2 - len(text)//2
    y = h//2
    stdscr.addstr(y, x, text)
    stdscr.refresh()


def test(stdscr):
    clr()
    print_center(stdscr, 'Hello')


def main(stdscr):
    # turn off cursor blinking
    curses.curs_set(0)

    # color scheme for selected row
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)

    # specify the current selected row
    current_row = 0

    # print the menu
    print_menu(stdscr, current_row)

    while 1:
        key = stdscr.getch()

        if key == curses.KEY_UP and current_row > 0:
            current_row -= 1
        elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN and current_row < len(menu)-1:
            current_row += 1
        elif key == curses.KEY_ENTER or key in [10, 13]:
            test(stdscr)
            stdscr.getch()
            # if user selected last row, exit the program
            if current_row == len(menu)-1:
                break

        print_menu(stdscr, current_row)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this but the statements "can you use curses syntax" and "have the curses syntax call the function" doesn't make sense? There's only Python syntax and some no-so-magic from the curses module's wrapper function that you pass `main` to which the wrapped calls by passing it a scr that curses handles/wraps IOT cleanly exit. curses and _curses are just modules based on C's ncurses.

I think you're on the right track though so your goal is achievable and while I didn't run your code it looks close as well. Yes you can write a basic python function. You could use the same default scr or you could also spawn a new initscr or derived scr (see the Python curses docs). I would start small and bind a single key to each option to ensure your callbacks work first. So if you bind 'h' to a help screen, just read getch and compare ord/char 'h', and if matches call a help() function (or create a callback of sorts by passing the function help to some other function to execute/wrap) so as to redraw the scr with help info. Then later work in cursors as you'll need to remember the cursor state and integrate with a list of callback functions.